# Python sphinx documentation -- autosummary links not consistent using autodocsumm extension

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, docstring

I am generating documentation for a Python project using the Sphinx autodocsumm extension with the following autosummary configuration to show a summary of only classes at the beginning of the document.

```
 Module1 module
----------------------------

.. automodule:: src.Module1
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
   :autosummary:
   :autosummary-no-nesting:
```

In the generated html, the summary class name hyperlinks are not consistent -- one is a path to a separate summary stub file, while the other just references an anchor in the main src.html file.

```
file:///project_path/docs/_build/html/src.Module1/src.Module1.Class1.html#src.Module1.Class1
file:///project_path/docs/_build/html/src.html#src.Module1.Class2
```

I can't figure out why the classes are being treated differently during the make.  The first one is a large class with many members while the second is a small class with just a few lines, so maybe there is some threshold for generating the stub file?  My preference is to not reference a separate file and only jump to the respective anchor within the main document for all summary links.

Is there a setting to control this behavior?

---

Edit: Upon further review, I don't think this has anything to do with autodocsumm after all.  I notice after doing the "make html" a subfolder is create only for the Class1 documentation while Class2 is referenced only in the main src.html file.

```
project_path/docs/_build/html/src.Module1/src.Module1.Class1.html
project_path/docs/_build/html/src.html
```

So... Why are these two classes treated differently? Also, is there any setting to prevent a separate folder and html file from being generated?

Comment: It appears that you use the autodocsumm extension (https://autodocsumm.readthedocs.io). You should make that clear in the question.

Comment: Thanks.  I edited my post to mention the autodocsumm extension.

Comment: "I don't think this has anything to do with autodocsumm after all." - Not sure what this means. Can you reproduce the problem without using autodocsumm?

Comment: Yes. I can reproduce the issue without using autodocsumm.  I can add links in my module docstring directly using cross referencing (e.g., :func:`Class1') and still reproduce the issue.  So, I realized only Class1 is being broken out into a separate folder and html file as shown in my edit.  I'm trying to figure out why it is doing it for Class1 but not Class2 and how to prevent it.

Comment: I think you need to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue... While narrowing my project down to a minimum reproducible example, I noticed an src.Module1 folder under docs that had rst files for Class1 only.

```
Project
    docs
        _build
        src.Module1
            Module1.Class1.rst
            src.Module1.Class1.rst
```

I'm not sure what I did to produced that folder, but after deleting it and rebuilding the Sphinx html, I am now getting the document anchors I expect directly in the src.html file:

```
file:///project_path/docs/_build/html/src.html#src.Module1.Class1
file:///project_path/docs/_build/html/src.html#src.Module1.Class2
```